# Restarting iPhone 6 Plus during Restore preventing the Restore from happening

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, restore

In an attempt to restore my iPhone 6 Plus, and update it to the latest iOS version, my iPhone 6 Plus keeps on restarting during the Restore. It happens during the stage where iTunes displays `Extracting software...`

After it's very quick reboot (It only flashes the white screen, and darkened Apple logo for a split second), it returns to the iTunes logo with and arrow and lightning charger below it. The problem is that iTunes then looses connection with the device and when it comes to actually restoring it - It fails.

It would be fantastic if anyone could help me with this.

As a note, I am using MacOS Sierra on a MacBook Pro (13 inch, Mid-2010) and iTunes is the latest version currently available to my device.

Comment: Have you tried DFU mode?

Comment: @Sirens Yeah. It still didn't work

Comment: Have you tried another computer?

Answer (score 1):

Please try by another USB connector.